# Color.GetHue(), Color.GetBrightness(), Color.GetSaturation() do not seem to provide the correct values

Tags: c#, colors, hsl

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.getbrightness?view=netframework-4.7.2) the three methods mentioned in the question title adhere to the HSL standard. However the methods are not providing the correct HSL values.

For example: I use [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) as test image. When I analyze the left upper pixel (position <0,0> in an image editor, it has the following values:

- RGB <225, 137, 127>
- HSL <6, 43, 88>

However my `Color` object concludes the following:

- RGB <225, 137, 127>
- HSL <6.12..., 0.62..., 0.69...>

  - scaled to the image editor units: <6, 62, 69>

My questions are:

- Is there a difference between HSL and what C# is using?
- If so, how to accommodate for it?

---

P.S.: I am using paint.net as image editor.

Comment: How did you load the `Color`? Any code to show?

Comment: Photoshop reads this color as 6,44,88 HSB ( not HSL!!)

Comment: The top one is HSV, the bottom is HSL

Comment: aah thanks :) that's the mixup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this helpful website](http://colorizer.org/):

```
RGB:       <225, 137, 127>
HSL (A):   <6.12, 62.03, 69.02>
HSV / HSB: <6.12, 43.56, 88.24>
```

We can conclude the `Color` is using HSL, and paint.net is using HSV / HSB. To be fair to paint.net, it does say that it's using HSV.